# How to stop adsl 2+ modem configuration page from appearing on wan and accessible only from lan?

Tags: networking

I have a DLink DSL-2520u ADSL2+ modem. When I access the page `http://192.168.1.1/`, it prompts for a username and password. Upon successful authentication, I see the modem configuration page.

If I am on a different network, I can also access the modems configuration via its public IP address.

How can I restrict access to the configuration page via the public IP address and only allow access via the internal IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a modem configuration page for enabling/disabling "remote configuration" or "remote adminstration".  This feature/selection might be under the "firewall" section.  Normally this feature should be disabled (at least that's the default setting for my modem.)